# GPU wait on texture

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm using shaders for **processing and rendering video frames**. So I need to update texture before each draw call. Everything works ok, but when I ran **OpenGL profiler** among others it showed me this warning:

> Your application attempted to update to a texture that is currently
>   used for rendering. This causes the CPU to wait for the GPU to finish
>   rendering. One way to fix this problem is to use a double or ring
>   buffered approach so that your application does not update a texture
>   that is used to as part of a drawing call. Another possibility is to
>   reorder operations in a way that allows for the GPU to finish using
>   the texture before it is updated.

I found this [article](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/OpenGLESApplicationDesign/OpenGLESApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008793-CH6-SW5). If I understood correctly, it is suggested to use second texture as additional buffer and use it interchangeably with the first one. So I've updated my code:

```
//use current texture
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, current_texture);

//update texture data
glTexImage2D(...);

//use the next texture and bind it
current_texture = (current_texture + 1)%2;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, current_texture);

[and then draw smth using this texture];
```

Works fine, but I still have the same warning from the profiler. Even if I use 3, 4 and more additional textures it doesn't help.

As I found later this issue can be solved using `Pixel Buffer Objects`, but it seems that **OpenGL ES 2.0** does not support them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: As a side note, never ever use `glTexImage2D` for *updating* texture data, only for *initialization/allocation* (and with the advent of `glTexStorage2D` `glTexImage2D` is finally completely obsolete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

OpenGL is an asynchronous API. Call may return much earlier than the actual rendering is performed. Let's have a look at this simplified drawing loop:

```
for(i=0; ; i++) {
    glBindTexture(…, tex[i % 2]);
    glTexSubImage2D(…);

    glBindTexture(…, tex[(i + 1) % 2]);
    draw_image();
}
```

Now here's the point, after the loop iterates i increments, which means we can rewrite this code as

```
glBindTexture(…, tex[0]);
glTexSubImage2D(…);

for(i=1; ; i++) {
    glBindTexture(…, tex[i % 2]);
    draw_image();
    glTexSubImage2D(…);
}
```

And I think it's now clear what happens.

Comment: @Boris: No what I mean is, that effectively your animation loop will already issue a texture update right after the drawing call. The later loop is, what you effectively already have in your program. You asked what was the cause for your problem. As how to solve it, there are various approaches, the most simple one being not to care about it, since OpenGL will effectively do double buffer when you redefine a texture's data while it's being used. Unless you'd actually use PBOs there's only little room for a performance gain if just juggling texture IDs.

Comment: But really, what could be the possible solution except the PBO and id juggling ?

Comment: @Boris: Well the most straigtforward thing to do is to perform all the texture updates (double buffered) for texID[(i+1)%n] _before_ doing the drawing. That way texture data upload and drawing happen in parallel into different texture objects.

Comment: @Boris - If you're trying to update textures that are still being used for rendering, you might either be trying to render faster than the screen updates or your rendering is taking more than 1/30th of a second (the video camera framerate) to run. The former doesn't seem likely with a video source, so for the latter, you're probably going to need to drop frames at some point. You could look at what I do here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage to handle processing of various video sources efficiently on iOS. In particular, look at the GPUImageVideoCamera class.